# Computing $\int^1_0 \frac{p^2-1}{\text{ln } p}dp$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Does anyone know the exact value of this integral?
>   $$\int^1_0 \frac{p^2-1}{\ln p}dp$$

I know that the approximate value is $1.09861...$. But I can't seem to get a figure on the exact value, or an antiderivative.

Comment: See [Frullani's integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html). Alternately, let $I(k)=\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{p^k-1}{\ln p}~dp$. Evaluate $I'(k)$, then write $I(k)=$ $=\displaystyle\int I'(k)~dk$, and finally, let $k=2$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\ln(p) = -t$. We have $p=e^{-t} \implies dp = -e^{-t} dt$. Hence, the integral is
\begin{align}
I & = \int_0^1 \dfrac{p^2-1}{\ln(p)}dp = \int_{\infty}^0\dfrac{e^{-2t}-1}{t} e^{-t}dt = \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-3t}-e^{-t}}tdt = \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{f(3t)-f(t)}tdt
\end{align}
where $f(t) = e^{-t}$. This is a [Frullani integral in the form
$$\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{f(ax)-f(bx)}xdx$$
whose value is
$$\ln\left(\dfrac{b}a\right)\left(f(0)-f(\infty)\right)$$](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f2z58boupqu5uwz/Frullani_Integral.pdf?dl=0)
In our case, $f(t) = e^{-t}$ with $a=3$ and $b=1$. Hence, we obtain the answer to be
$$\boxed{\color{red}{\ln\left(\dfrac13\right)\cdot\left(0-1\right) = \ln(3) \approx 1.0986122886681096913952452369225257046474905578227494}}$$

---

In general, by the same argument, it is easy to see that
$$I(a) = \int_0^1 \dfrac{p^{\alpha}-1}{\ln(p)}dp = \ln(1+\alpha) \text{  for all  }\alpha>-1$$